# How to automatically get the registry key of 64/32 bit machines while running an application?

Tags: c#, .net, registry, regedit

In my application I need to read registry key name of another appliation ie installed on both 32 bit and 64 bit windows machines.How can i read the registry key names from 64/42 bit path?

```
for 64 bit path
***************
key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\App\App.INI\AppName");

for 32 bit path
***************
key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\App\App.INI\AppName");
```

I need to do it as a common code for both path.If it is 64 bit machine,need to get the path till wow6432node automatically.Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RegistryView` with one of the *Enums* and `OpenBaseKey` with your original path `SOFTWARE\App\App.INI\AppName` depending on your bitness

[RegistryView Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registryview?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Specifies which registry view to target on a 64-bit operating system.
>
> On the 64-bit version of Windows, portions of the registry are stored
>   separately for 32-bit and 64-bit applications. There is a 32-bit view
>   for 32-bit applications and a 64-bit view for 64-bit applications.

**Example**

```
using (var baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64))
{
   using (var subKey = baseKey.OpenSubKey("blah", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.FullControl))
   {
      if (subKey != null)
      {
         var value =  subKey.GetValue("Somekey");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: How can I redirect to 64/32 bit path without defining 2 different paths?

Comment: @Michael: Both the keys shown in your question are in the 32-bit view of the registry.